# Why am I able to map a RDD with the SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, rdd

The SparkContext is not serializable. It is meant to be used on the driver, thus can someone explain the following ?

*Using the spark-shell, on yarn, and Spark version 1.6.0*

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1))
rdd.foreach(x => print(sc))
```

**Nothing happens on the client (prints executors-side)**

*Using the spark-shell, local master, and Spark version 1.6.0*

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1))
rdd.foreach(x => print(sc))
```

**Prints "null" on the client**

*Using pyspark, local master, and Spark version 1.6.0*

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1])
def _print(x):
    print(x)
rdd.foreach(lambda x: _print(sc))
```

**Throws an Exception**

I also tried the following :

*Using the spark-shell, and Spark version 1.6.0*

```
class Test(val sc:org.apache.spark.SparkContext) extends Serializable{}
val test = new Test(sc)
rdd.foreach(x => print(test))
```

Now it finally throws a *java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext*

---

Why does it works in Scala when I only print sc ? Why do I have a null reference when it should have thrown a NotSerializableException (or so I thought ...)

Comment: Same with `SparkSession` in Spark 2.1.1, it prints also  `null` (althoug `SparkSession` implements `Serializable`